# Is it possible to called a Parse defined cloud code function from the cloud?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have several cloud code functions defined like...

```
Parse.define("getPostsNearby"...
Parse.define("getPostsToday"...
Parse.define("getPostsBlah"...
```

The only difference is the parameters they take in.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a function...

```
Parse.define("getPosts"...
```

That would analyse the input parameters and then run the relevant cloud code function? Sort of like a routing function. So if a geoPoint is passed into the parameters it will call the `getPostsNearby` cloud code function and then return the results from that.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I have not tried it before but maybe `Parse.Cloud.run` could work, otherwise you should use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`

Comment: @eth3lbert excellent. That looks perfect. It even returns a Promise so I can run it just how I would like. Stick it as an answer and I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Parse.Cloud.run(name, data, options)` or `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(options)`

ref. [Parse.Cloud.run](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.run), [Parse.Cloud.httpRequest](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.httpRequest)